# Why isn't the following function selecting all the checkboxes inside this directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

The following directive has two tabels: one with checkboxes and another without checkboxes. It also has a function which selects all the checkboxes:

```
  .directive('tableList', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      template: '<button ng-if="listAll" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">' +
      'Launch demo modal' +
    '</button>' +
    '<table class="table table-stripped">' +
    '<thead>' +
        '<th>SOME CODE</th>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</thead>' +
    '<tbody>' +
      '<tr ng-repeat="item in listThis">' +
        '<th scope="row">{{$index + 1}}</th>' +
        '<td><a href="#/groups/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a></td>' +
        '<td>SOME CODE</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</tbody>' +
      '</table>' +
      '<div ng-if="listAll" class="" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">' +
    '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
      '<div class="modal-content">' +
        '<div class="modal-header">' +
          '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>' +
          '<h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-body">' +
          '<table class="table table-stripped list-all">' +
        '<thead>' +
          '<tr>' +
            '<th><input type="checkbox" ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()" /></th>' +
            '<th>SOME CODE</th>' +
          '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '<tbody>' +
          '<tr ng-repeat="item in listAll">' +
            '<th scope="row"><input type="checkbox" value="0" ng-model="item.selected"></th>' +
            '<td><a href="#/groups/{{item.id}}">{{item.name}}</a></td>' +
            '<td>SOME CODE</td>' +
          '</tr>' +
        '</tbody>' +
          '</table>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div class="modal-footer">' +
          '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div><!-- /.modal-content -->' +
    '</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->' +
      '</div><!-- /.modal -->',
      scope: {
    listThis: "=",
    listAll: "=",
    submit: "&"
      },
      controller: function() {
      },
      link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
    scope.checkAll = function() {
      if (scope.selectedAll) {
        scope.selectedAll = true
      } else {
        scope.selectedAll = false
      }
      angular.forEach(scope.listAll, function (item) {
        item.selected = scope.selectedAll
      })
    }
      }
  };
})
```

The checkboxes work. This is how it looks like if I check the first item:

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "name": "User 1",
    "selected": true
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "User 2",
    "selected": false
  },
  {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "User 3",
    "selected": false
  }
]
```

But when I click the checkboxe that checks all the items nothing happens:

[image]

What could be the problem?

This is how I'm using the directive:

```
  <table-list
list-this="users"
list-all="users"
submit="submit(event)">
  </table-list>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
if (scope.selectedAll) {
    scope.selectedAll = true
} else {
    scope.selectedAll = false
}
```

There is no point in this statement because `scope.selectedAll` will never become true if it is initially false and vice versa - it just never changes value. May be you meant:

```
if (scope.selectedAll) {
    scope.selectedAll = false
} else {
    scope.selectedAll = true
}
```

Comment: hey it worked thanks. weird I took it from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/deeptechtons/TKVH6/